# Multiple documentation created for the same API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

In my project I configure routing as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiLogin",
    routeTemplate: "Api/Default/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "Api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" },
    constraints: null,
    handler: sessionHandler
);
```

One routing doesn't use a `HttpMessageHandler` whilst the other does.

When generating the documentation with `Swagger`, it's generation duplicates (one for each routing).

Is there a way to suppress certain routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Swashbuckle, and I am not an expert of it. I followed this [discussion](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/228) on github and came up with the following solution. You need to create the following class:

```
public class FilterRoutesDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{  
     public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
     {
          var keys = swaggerDoc.paths.Keys.Where(x => x.Contains("/api/Default/")).ToList();

           foreach (var key in keys)
               swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(key);
     }
}
```

and then add the following line in SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c => { c.DocumentFilter<FilterRoutesDocumentFilter>(); }
```

It seems to work fine. Hope this helps.